# How can i use the announce list one by one in a single php code?

Tags: php

I am getting torrent announces by requesting in php like (example)

.........../announce
....../announce
......../announce

(Since announcelist may be of any numbers)

Below is the code:

```
$counter = count($torrent_data['announce-list']);
if ($counter > 0) {
    $announcelist = ($torrent_data['announce-list']);
    echo 'Announce list:<br />';
    $c = count($announcelist);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++) {
        echo $announcelist[$i]['0'] . '<br/>';
    }
} else {
    $announce = $torrent_data['announce'];
    echo 'Announce:' . $announce;
}
```

Now i have a php code where i actually want to request all this announce one by one to get seeds, leechers etc...

Now my question is, how can i use the announce list one by one in a single php code? Example:

```
$ret = $scraper->scrape('http://tracker.tld:port/announce',array('0000000000000000000000000000000000000000'));
```

Please anyone help me.

Comment: uh, you are getting them one-by-one with your for() loop.

Comment: Hi Marc i can't get you, how can i use for() for the announcelist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure what you mean by request announce one-by-one, but you should be able to do in the for loop you have there, as you're already displaying them one-by-one

```
$result = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++) {
  echo $announcelist[$i]['0'] . '<br/>';
  $result[] = $scraper->scrape($announcelist[$i]['0'];
}
```

(also don't forget to add it to the `else` branch

EDIT:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($announcelist as $announce){
  $result[] = $scraper->scrape($announce['0']);
}
```

This will produce an array $result containing all the info for each of the announces

Comment: Hi @Seth, Please check back the question which i have edited back

Comment: $scraper->scrape($announcelist[$i]['0']) ?

Comment: $announcelist[$i]['0'] will give all the announcelist at once. But i want only single announce list one by one to get work, because $ret gets work only in single announcelist.

Comment: So what does the $i represent? What is the difference between $announcelist[0]['0'] and $announcelist[1]['0'] ?

Comment: $i is the order number for the announce list. $announcelist[0]['0'] will give the first announce and $announcelist[1]['0'] will give the second announce and like this it will go on till the total announce list $c

Comment: Well that's what you need, or?

Comment: yeah but different torrent may have different number of announcelist. So how can i put $announcelist[0]['0'], $announcelist[1]['0'], $announcelist[2]['0'] upto the total number of announcelist in the $ret, which must work automatically in the php.

Comment: I edited the answer, that should work for any number of announce list, altough you are also able to do it in the for loop. Just put the new code anywhere after $announcelist has been defined.

Comment: If it helped an upvote and accepting the answer would be appreciated :)

Comment: Sorry, Vote Up require 15 reputation which i don't have. Then Also Thank you very much